# Formatting a Single Line in Textarea

Tags: formatting, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` which I'm appending to dynamically using JS.

I'd like to format it so the header row being appended is bold:

```
some previous content...

NEW HEADER ROW TO BE MADE BOLD

New additional content...

...
```

So the header row would essentially be wrapped in a `<strong>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without punctuation and using jQuery, this works for me:

```
$('#textbox').change(function(){
    $('#example').html($('#textbox').text().replace(/([A-Z\s]+)\n/g, "<strong>$1</strong>"))
})
```

In this snippet, 'textbox' is the id of the textarea and 'example' is the preview div.

Answer (score 0):

css first line? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp

Comment: Maybe a saver bet is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::first-line there is some doubt on w3schools, http://w3fools.com/ Also add the proposed css to prevent that this answer is rendered useless if the link is no longer online